# How to create NSHTTPURLResponse with a specific status code in 10.6

Tags: objective-c, macos, osx-snow-leopard, foundation

Is it possible to create `NSHTTPURLResponse` instance with a specific status code in Mac OS X 10.6?

I know about

```
- (instancetype)initWithURL:(NSURL *)url
                 statusCode:(NSInteger)statusCode
                HTTPVersion:(NSString *)HTTPVersion
               headerFields:(NSDictionary *)headerFields
```

But it is available starting from 10.7. Any ideas how to accomplish this in 10.6?